# jQuery FadeIn/FadeOut each element sequently

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have quotes on my site that I want to show up one at a time

```
<div class="quotes">
    <p>Quote1</p>
    <p>Quote2</p>
    <p>Quote3</p>
    <p>Quote4</p>
</div>
```

After page loads I want the first one to be visible and fade after, lets say, 2 seconds of delay, and next one appear right after, then second one fade out after delay and so on.
I know how to do that with just CSS, but need something more efficient and the whole thing has to repeat infinitely.
Thank you!

Comment: So what you have tried? What's your issue?

Comment: Wich way are you using with css?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan issue css code is too big and if I want to change, lets say delay, I have to change it everywhere

Comment: @Danko just created bunch of animations each firing up with different delays

Comment: You shouldn't use jQuery animations if you want it to be efficient.

Comment: @caeth why jquery isn't efficient?

Comment: @Danko Check this out: http://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can cycle your quotes (adjust animation duration to your taste):

```js
var $quotes = $('.quotes p'),
    index = 0;

$quotes.eq(index++).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(function next() {
    $quotes.eq(index++ % $quotes.length).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(next);
});
```

```css
.quotes p {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #C1C3D2;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quotes">
    <p>Quote1</p>
    <p>Quote2</p>
    <p>Quote3</p>
    <p>Quote4</p>
</div>
```